# Selenium : pop up

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need a help regarding a pop-up that shows up when I run a selenium script.

What I want to do , is to accept the certificate. The problem is that I don't have access to any elements when I inspect the elements.

You'll find attached a screenshot of the certificate.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

I tried to do :
 `driver.switch_to_alert().accept()`

I tried many other things but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.